# What does a channel mean for FULLY connected feedforward neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology

I only know the meaning of channel in convolutional neural network, and it refers to the number of feature maps we obtain from a convolutional block (conv + relu + pool). For images the input layer has 3 channels.

However, in a popular paper: neural radiance field https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08934.pdf the author insists on the outputs having different channels, despite the network being a feedforward neural net. See figure 7.

Does channel in feedforward neural networks refer to the number of outputs? It is difficult for me to visualize because I can only imagine one set of input going through a network and producing one set of output per layer. This output is of course high dimensional, it is a matrix $W$ multiplied by a vector $x$ and that's one vector.

Now it has occurred to me that if your input is an image, and you somehow "slice" this image $N$ times and send these $N$ components of image through the same network, then you would get $N$ "channels". Is this the correct interpretation?